# revive or resurrection

Tags: word-choice

I am developing a zombie game and I am not sure whicht word fit better in the next context:

A player that kills zombies, get killed by them, however the player have a "skill" that let him (revive or resurrection).

How would you call the "skill", Revive or resurrection?

Comment: So the players are like the zombies? :)  Do you want a verb or a noun? Do you want the name for what they do, or a word to express the act of doing it?

Comment: If I were making such a zombie game, I'd say that the players can **undie** and that each **undying** requires X points.

Comment: player are humans, I don't know if I want a verb or a noun, I just want to be clear and correct, so all the people understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Resurrect X* is used if X is dead.

*Revive X* can be  used if X merely passed out, but was still alive.

If the player is actually dead then *resurrect* would be more proper if something was bringing him/her back to life.  However it can be argued that if the player dies, and can do something to become alive again right away, that *revive* would be more appropriate.  *Revive* has more of an implication of "easily reversible" than *resurrect*.

Comment: No, *revive* can also be used if X is dead. My dictionary (OLD) defines it as: "restore to life or consciousness". An example of this usage is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiopulmonary_resuscitation): "There are cases where CPR, defibrillation, and advanced warming techniques have *revived* victims after substantial periods of hypothermia."

Comment: Right, but if X is not actually dead but just unconscious, *resurrect* is less appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The player die when he receive 5 hits from zombies, if you see an ad or special hability, you can 'revive' instant, so probably revive will fit better here